# How to detect HTML in clipboard data using Qt

Tags: html, regex, qt

I have a rich text editor I'm working on where I need to parse and clean data from the clipboard when appropriate. Whenever the text being pasted contains HTML, I will clean it up and update the text field with the correct html.

However, when there is no html in the clipboard, there is no need for me to run the html cleaning tool.

My first thought was to use Regex and check for any html tag in there, but I'm not sure this is the best solution for this problem as it can cause more headaches in the long run with false positives, etc.

My question is, how can I detect some HTML in the clipboard?
Is there a an elegant way to solve this problem without having to resort to Regex?

Comment: I think it's down to applying heuristics if the text looks like it contains html markup. The shorter the text is, the more unreliable it gets

Answer (score -1):

may be one of these functions:

```
bool QDomDocument::setContent(...)
```

This function reads the XML document from the string text, returning true if the content was successfully parsed; otherwise returns false. Since text is already a Unicode string, no encoding detection is done

Addition for a clipboard's mixed data:

```
// get a html data from a junk
QString htmlText = cliboardString.section("</html>", -2, 0,QString::SectionIncludeTrailingSep)
              .section("<html", 1,-1,String::SectionIncludeLeadingSep);
// check for a validness, correctness etc.
if( !htmlText.isEmpty() ) {
    QDomDocument::setContent(htmlText,...
}
```

Comment: Since the content comes from the clipboard - therefore likely to be broken html - your function would always return false. Thus, I would always be assuming its not html and would be saving invalid html believing that the content is just pure text.